# How to specify the default JSON body in Swagger-PHP?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

I want to specify the default JSON body for a POST request in Swagger-PHP. My annotations look like this:

```
/**
 * Setup order
 *
 * @SWG\Post(
 *      path="/order/setup",
 *      operationId="setupOrder",
 *      tags={"Orders"},
 *      summary="Setup an order with status draft.",
 *      description="Setup an order with status draft",
 *      consumes={"application/json"},
 *      @SWG\Parameter(
 *          name="body",
 *          in="body",
 *          default="{}",
 *          description="Json order info body (customer and products info)",
 *          required=true,
 *          @SWG\Schema(type="string")
 *      ),
 *      @SWG\Response(
 *          response=200,
 *          description="successful operation"
 *       ),
 *       @SWG\Response(response=400, description="Bad request"),
 *       security={
 *           {"api_key_security_example": {}}
 *       }
 *     )
 *
 */
```

As you can see I'm trying to achieve the default value with `default="{}",` but Swagger UI ignores this value and places 'string' instead as default value:

[image]

How can I change the 'string' part to a default JSON object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve as you expected by modifying your `@SWG\Parameter()`.

Example (look at example of the property):

```
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="body",
 *     in="body",
 *     description="User email used to create account.",
 *     required=true,
 *     @SWG\Schema(@SWG\Property(property="email", type="string", example="email@example.com")),
 *   )
```

[image: This annotation will generate something like this]

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below.

```
/**
 * Setup order
 * @SWG\Post(
 *      path="/order/setup",
 *      operationId="setupOrder",
 *      tags={"Orders"},
 *      summary="Setup an order with status draft.",
 *      description="Setup an order with status draft",
 *      consumes={"application/json"},
 *      @SWG\Parameter(
 *          name="body",
 *          in="body",
 *          default="{}",
 *          description="Json order info body (customer and products info)",
 *          required=true,
 *          @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/testDefinitions")
 *      ),
 *      @SWG\Response(
 *          response=200,
 *          description="successful operation"
 *       ),
 *       @SWG\Response(response=400, description="Bad request"),
 *       security={
 *           {"api_key_security_example": {}}
 *       }
 *     )
 *  @SWG\Definition(
 *      definition="PlanResponse",
 *      example={
 *         "type":"string"
 *      }
 *     )
 */
```

Thanks,